# Compilation error is displayed while running the given program

Tags: java, runtime-error

I just started practicing competitive programming on codeforces.I faced a problem in solving a question. it is showing compile time error

```
import java.util.*;
public class A71
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n ;
        n=sc.nextInt();
        String a[] = new String[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int l=a[i].length();
            System.out.println(a[i].charAt(0)+""+(l-2)+""+a[i].charAt(l-1));
        }
    }
}
```

The error which is displayed is below

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at A71.main(A71.java:17)

Runtime error: exit code is 11
```

Comment: that is a runtime exception, not a compilation problem (not every stacktrace is a compilation issue). apparently, you have an empty String and you try to get the first character out of it. My guess, it's here: a[i].charAt(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stultuske pointed out in the comments, you receive this error due to access on an empty String. Try to replace sc.nextLine() with sc.next() in a loop